# In "Sound Of My Voice", what was the meaning of the first scene with Carol?

Tags: sound-of-my-voice

Carol being the self-identified Justice Department agent (or was she?). She checks the room for bugs, and then examines a photo with an apparently heavy heart. Is there any more meaning to it than that?

Comment: Chris! I've only seen the film once, long ago, but both Brit Marling and Zal Batmanglij are on my twitter feed, so I've sent them both a link to this page - if I hear anything back, I'll let you know. Zal was a guest at the Edinburgh Film Festival last summer with The East and I interviewed him for my website - he's a really sound guy.

Answer (score 2):

I received a somewhat oblique tweet back from Zal a few minutes ago - curse that character limit!

"dunno how to respond. yes, no, maybe so? what we think is less interesting. happy day."

If it helps, he and Brit do hope at some point to revisit that world and the further stories - we spoke about *Sound of My Voice* when we met last year as well as the film he was promoting, *The East*.

More info [here](http://geekchocolate.co.uk/zal-batmanglij-writer-and-director/).